# Is there a way to avoid the relative path in TestCafe?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I was wondering if anybody has found a solution to the relative path hell in TestCafe, so instead of writing this in my fixtures:

```
import LoginPage from "../pages/citizen/login-page";
```

I would like to write:

```
import LoginPage from "Citizen/login-page";
```

Currently using:

- testcafe: 1.7.1
- nodejs 8.12.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `path` module for directory resolution.

Since you are using ES5 import statements, you need to first download `@types/node` dependency.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

Your import statement code:

```
import * as path from 'path';
const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, '/login-page');
```